# getting logged-in user's details on another user's facebook profile tab

Tags: facebook, profile

I have a Facebook application that has a user profile tab. The specs of the app dictate that the layout of the profile tab should be different depending on whether a user is looking at their own profile, or someone else is looking.

Whenever I try to print_r FB's signed request details, the profile_id is always the same as the user_id, even if I am looking at the profile as another user.

Is there another way I can get this information, or is it not possible using Facebook's current setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook sends visitor id only after they interact with your tab in some way, but not during the first visit.

Comment: Thanks! What counts as an interaction with the tab?

Comment: @Lowgain Interaction is like clicking on something or submitting a form. I can't give you exact answer as they removed the only doc page that had this info.

Answer (score 0):

In theory the [Canvas `signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas) functionality is meant to solve this issue too, but I'm having the same issue around the user needing to interact with the tab first.

Personally, I think that's stupid with respect to `signed_request` functionality, as it looks like I need to request permissions I don't need in order to get it to do what I thought the purpose of the functionality change was (see [#3362040](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362040) for an example).

Griping aside, though, you might find the `signed_request` functionality helpful for this.